# nginx. Загрузка публичного PGP ключа

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

Здраствуйте! Заранее спасибо за помошь!

https://nginx.org/ru/linux_packages.html

Здесь написано:

Для Debian/Ubuntu, для проверки подлинности подписи репозитория nginx, и чтобы избавиться от предупреждений об отсутствующем PGP-ключе во время установки пакета nginx, необходимо добавить ключ, которым были подписаны пакеты и репозиторий nginx, в связку ключей программы apt. Загрузите этот ключ с нашего веб-сайта и добавьте его в связку ключей программы apt, выполнив команду:

```
sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key
```

Как загрузить этот ключ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот ключ, приведенный в инструкции по Вашей ссылке, `https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key` командой, приведенной в вопросе.

После загрузки выполните `apt update` и предупреждение пропадет.

Однострочник:

```
wget -q -O- "https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key" | sudo apt-key add -
```

В две строки:

```
wget -q "https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key"
sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key
```

П.С. Так лень запоминать как правильно писать это заклинание через `apt-key adv`.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!